# Linux reboots by itself after reaching login screen

Tags: linux, boot, login, desktop-environment, reboot

After deleting Windows 11, I installed Nobara Linux, but my laptop reboots itself after 5 seconds in login screen. And it doesn't matter if I managed to enter password or move to tty, cause it reboots anyway.

Same with Ubuntu, Fedora and Garuda. Only distro which works without this bug is Manjaro Bungie Edition and Garuda in recovery mode, which is basically tty.

Maybe worth mentioning that there is still Windows boot manager in BIOS.

My laptop is HP VICTUS 16(Ryzen 5 5600 and Nvidia RTX 3050)

PS: Sorry for bad English, and I am thankful for any solution or advice.

Comment: 1. Update UEFI ("BIOS"), if available; 2: If you intend to have Linux only then you can disable Secure Boot so try that before anything else; 3. It goes without saying that you MUST install any OS in UEFI mode (Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode may still be an option in the firmware but that hardware really can't work properly unless with a current OS in proper UEFI mode).

Comment: @ChanganAuto Did you notice that the user says they can boot and that the system appears to run correctly (even presenting a login screen), but that it reboots after a short while? The things you suggest seem applicable in the scenario where the system was unbootable.  I might obviously be wrong, but you don't say what the actual cause may be.

Comment: @Kusalananda The issue is either buggy firmware or instability due to the absence or impossibility to boot with Nvidia proprietary drivers, hence the suggestion to try after disabling Secure Boot. And it can be both in dialectic action resulting in crash/reboot. And the absolute need for UEFI mode is self-explanatory considering the hardware. We should consider all the possible scenarios in maqchines really not designed for anything other than Windows. (...)

Comment: And there's more unfortunately: If it has AMD IOMMU settings it may need changing and/or additional kernel parameters.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for spelling out your thinking. Much appreciated.

Comment: My main bet in on the Nvidia drivers. One thing Manjaro does very well is the automated installation of those drivers while Ubuntu is opt-in (and many users forgot to tick that option), don't know about the others. That being the case @Nikson_230 you must boot in "safe graphics mode" (or with `nomodeset`) and then install the recommended Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do so.